# Simple color management for print & web

Tags: color-profile, color-reproduction

I'm starting out a small business as a print & web designer. I need to stay low on costs at this point. I did the first design on a laptop, got some money in advance, purchased an EIZO CS230 display and got some more clients after that. I've found a good printer and we will print some color samples prior to production run, that's not a problem, and it is absolutely necessary in my current conditions.

However, what so-so settings do you recommend for the display to get the most out of it? Contrast, color temperature, etc. I thought EIZO ColorNavigator would somewhat solve this for me but it turned up to be useless without calibration. I've set up the monitor manually to 5000K, brightness 80 cd/m2 and gamma 2.20 (just copied the default settings for Printing in ColorNavigator).

I will of course either hire somebody or solve it myself later, but money need to go somewhere else now.

Comment: You need to have a hardware calibrator anything less is not an option

Comment: I *know*, but the question is about how to get the most from what I have now. If there's nothing, I just don't care at this moment.

Comment: Well your not supposed to adjust the monitor from the factory setting then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to differentiate the settings you change in the monitor and the changes you make on the graphics card, internally using the software.

The color temperature, basic contrast, and brightness are set on the monitor responding to the working environment.

The standard viewing condition for print reproduction is D50, but the standard for sRGB is D65.

It is a bit complex why the different settings. Look at page 28 of the Fogra specification. https://www.fogra.org/en/fogra-standardization/digital-printing-2-48/digital-printing-standardization.html

So this can be discussed a bit. In my opinion for a design studio, I would use the  D65 as the D50 is too warm, especially if an important part of your work is web design. But for print design, if you have a viewing box set to D50 illuminant, the screen should match it. But some industries now are using D65 as the standard illuminant.

That leaves setting the gamma internally on the graphics card configuration.

If you are using Windows use the Color Calibration tool on the control panel. 
This is the most important step on a basic equipment calibration.